# Category layout update not working from admin in ultimento theme Magento

Tags: magento, zend-framework, layout, categories

> I a using a ultimo theme for my magento site
>
> In this the category page layout is set to 2column left
>
> but i need to set 1 column for some categories
>
> . I have tried to change the layout from the admin for those
>   categories but there is no effect
>
> , it still shows 2colum left.

can you please suggest me how can i get this.

thanks

Comment: if your store is multistore setup then please check storewise category display setting

Comment: i have change this for particular store view but it stills same